# Django rest framework self.objects.all() as variable

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have parent id in my model:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)
```

and in serializer:

```
parent = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required=False)
```

It shows me selectbox with items: "Category object" as it saves all items like that. What I can do to show Category names?

And there is no None option in selectbox.

Another question:
How to show Categories in select with parent=None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you model `Category`,define `__unicode__` method

```
class Category(models.Model):
   //your fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Didn't changed, created new object, but gives same name, Category object, for both

Comment: Worked in python 2, but not in python 3

Comment: Ok, solved using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods

Comment: @EminMastizada yep, that is the idea, using unicode to repr the object string.

Comment: Thanks @levi , it solved problem. Other problem solved too, adding object.filter(parent=None)